# Проверять текст в listview

Tags: java, android, espresso

Не совсем понимаю принцип работы метода представленным в офф.документации `withItemContent`. 
Скопировав сам метод отсюда [офф пример](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/testapp/LongListMatchers.java)

Пытаюсь вызвать нужные мне ресурсы по тексту следующим образом:

```
        onData(withItemContent("Accounts"))
            .inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list))
            .atPosition(1)
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()))
```

В данном случае мне нужно проверять не только позицию, но и текст.
К примеру данная реализация работает без проблем, но здесь я не проверяю текст:

```
onData(anything())
            .inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list))
            .atPosition(1)
            .perform(click())
    pressBack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что Вам мешает проверять текст во втором методе просто дополнив его:

```
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(hasDescendant(withText("text"))))
```